# Can I change the keyboard shortcut for copy & paste?

Tags: clipboard, shortcut-keys, dvorak

Recently I switched to a DVORAK keyboard layout & wish to change the current key combination for copy & paste from *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd>* to *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd>* to allow more ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a simple solution like many users. [There is autokey-gtk workaround](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764318).

Comment: Nice; it'll  have to do for now. I'll keep this Q going for a bit in hopes of a fix

Comment: Solved....bought a keyboard that could store macros.